# Custom core translation in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, translation

I am new to Joomla and looking for something related to the custom translation in Joomla.

How can I add my own language in Joomla if it is not listed by default? Is there anything available in Joomla by which I can add create those languages which are currently not available in Joomla system?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/how-to-joomla/how-to-install-a-new-language-in-joomla-3

Comment: @Lodder I have already done that but my language is not available in Joomla.

Comment: Ok so you've installed a language. If you go to **Extensions** >> **Languages**, do you see it in the list?

Comment: @Lodder Yes I can add all other languaes ,going to extentions->languages but my language is not available in Joomla, you can check yourself ,just search this 'pashto'

Comment: What do you mean "not available"? Do you mean from the language switcher module?

Comment: @Lodder Have you tried to search this language 'pashto' ? let me know plz

Comment: @Lodder my main question is "Is there anything available in Joomla by which I can add create those languages which are not available in joomla system uptill now", for example I can add new custom language and I have to add all its words which I need in my application,that custom language would not be usefull for other people but it is only for my application,ie my custom created lanugae having limited words added by me?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to create your own Joomla language pack for Pashto, because this language is not available as a [Translation pack](http://community.joomla.org/translations/joomla-3-translations.html).

You'll find a complete guide on how to create a Joomla core language pack [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Making_a_Language_Pack_for_Joomla). If you only need to translate the Front end, you might want to skip to the instructions for [Site only pack](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Making_a_Language_Pack_for_Joomla#The_Site-only_pack).

If you don't want to create everything from scratch, you can also download an existing translation from a language similar to Pashto (you know better than me what language that would be, if any). Then extract all the files, and change the translations. Also make sure you edit all `.php` files included. The tutorial I mentioned earlier explains what the different `.php` files do.

Also remember to name your files correctly with the corresponding language tag. [Joomla uses the ISO system to create language tags](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Making_a_Language_Pack_for_Joomla#Standard_ISO_codes_for_naming_language_packages) using:

- the languagecode
- the countrycode

I believe the correct language tag for Pastho would be `ps_AF`.

Good luck!